# Integral inequality for $ (\int_0^1 (u_1v_1+u_2v_2) )^2+ (\int_0^1 (u_2v_1-u_1v_2) )^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, definite-integrals, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am interested in the following inequality: $$\left (\displaystyle\int_0^1 u_1(x)v_1(x)+u_2(x)v_2(x)\ dx\right )^2+\left (\displaystyle\int_0^1 u_2(x)v_1(x)-u_1(x)v_2(x)\ dx\right )^2\leq \left ( \displaystyle\int_0^1 u_1^2(x)+u_2^2(x)\ dx\right  )\cdot\left ( \displaystyle\int_0^1 v_1^2(x)+v_2^2(x)\ dx\right  )$$

$\bullet$ I proved that $LHS\leq 2\cdot RHS$ using Cauchy inequality, but $2$ is not the best posible constant.

$\bullet$ Also, if one of the four function is $0$ or two of them are equal then the inequality follows with ease via Cauchy Inequality.

I wonder if this inequality holds anytime.

Comment: Have you realized that by expanding, you can simplify a lot your inequality ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With $u = u_1 + iu_2$ and $v = v_1 + iv_2$ we have
$$
 u \overline v = \bigl( u_1 v_1 + u_2 v_2 \bigr)
+ i \bigl( u_2 v_1 - u_1 v_2 \bigr) \, , \\
|u|^2 = u_1^2 + u_2^2 \, ,\\
|v|^2 = v_1^2 + v_2^2 \, ,
$$
so that your inequality is equivalent to
$$
 \left | \int_0^1 u(x) \overline{v(x)}\, dx\right|^2 \le
\int_0^1 |u(x)|^2 \, dx \cdot \int_0^1 |v(x)|^2 \, dx \, .
$$
That is the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for complex-valued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2).